# check if windows service exists and is running

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, windows-services

how can I add a condition to my code below to also check if the services are running?

```
For Each s As ServiceController In ServiceController.GetServices()
    If s.ServiceName = "test" Or s.ServiceName = "test1" Or s.ServiceName = "test2" Then
        s.Stop()
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Did you bother to look it up? See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller_properties.aspx

Comment: I am new to VB and found it a struggle to add the function to the above, thus why I have asked the question

Comment: That doesn't tell me why you didn't look it up, same as I did.

Comment: Like I said. I was having trouble adding the additional function. Thanks for your support

Comment: Great. Why did you not google for the ServiceController class? You would have found the Status property.

Comment: I did, but was having trouble combining "search for service name" and "if running stop" together, which is why I thought I would ask the community.

Comment: I just searched for ["ServiceController"](https://www.google.com/search?q=ServiceController) and found ["ServiceController class"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.aspx) as the first hit.

Comment: From there, it's an easy step to ["ServiceController.Status Property"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.status.aspx), which says "Gets the status of the service that is referenced by this instance." See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontrollerstatus.aspx for the possible values, which include `ServiceControllerStatus.Running`.

Comment: Since you already know that you're using the `ServiceController` class, it's pretty easy to find what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the Status of the ServiceController and only stop it if it is running. You should also check that it *can* be stopped:

```
For Each s As ServiceController In ServiceController.GetServices()
    If s.ServiceName = "test" OrElse 
       s.ServiceName = "test1" OrElse 
       s.ServiceName = "test2" Then
        If s.CanStop AndAlso s.Status = ServiceControllerStatus.Running Then
            s.Stop()
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Note that you should use `OrElse` and `AndAlso` whenever possible to make your code more efficient

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I will have a look later

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Service Controller Status property and the Running enumeration as such:

```
For Each s As ServiceController In ServiceController.GetServices()
                If (s.ServiceName = "test" Or s.ServiceName = "test1" Or s.ServiceName = "test2") And (s.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.Running)) Then
                    s.Stop()
                End If
            Next
```

This has some drawbacks in that it only returns true if it is running and there are many states a service can be in.

ContinuePending
Paused
PausePending
Running
StartPending
Stopped
StopPending

So you may want to check if it is stopped and if that is false then you could stop it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I will have a look later